# How to make a date interval in a MySQL query?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I want to make a date interval in a MySQL query. The date is extracted dynamically from an HTML Form and I want to search if something is between 2 days after and after a fixed date. I've made an example but it's not working well.

```
SELECT * FROM `sessions` WHERE `start_date` = '2014-05-12'
 or `start_date` between DATE_SUB(start_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
and DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Any other propositions ?

Comment: `DATE_SUB(start_date...` is this right or you meant some variable or now()/curdate() instead of start_date?

Comment: It’s the right column wich contain the date

Comment: ok, let me put it this way, every x is between x - 1 and x + 1 :)

Comment: i think you should remove `start_date = '2014-05-12'
 OR`

Comment: we talk about dates right here it's not numbers :/

Comment: @catalinetu the idea is that i fix a date and a search things 2 day after and before this date

Comment: This query is like saying SELECT 2 BETWEEN 1 AND 3. I think it will always be true.

Comment: Yes i know i'm looking for an ohter possiblity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong every time this query is resulting all rows from the `sessions` table. Let's take a look at this particular part of the query,

`start_date between DATE_SUB(start_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
and DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)`,

So if the start_date value of a row is 22-07-2014 the query translates to,
`start_date between 21-07-2014 and 23-07-2014)`

So every row satisfies the condition as every date x is between x - 1th day and x + 1th day.

So if you want to execute the query to find a date between a certain interval, try

`start_date between DATE_SUB('$start_date', INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
and DATE_ADD('$start_date', INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

instead. Note that `'$start_date'` is a php variable that is the date you are comparing the row with.

Comment: Yes you're right so how i can dispaly just the rows which come 2 days before and after the date that i fixed